# XSLT to call secondary XML based on first XML element/attribute

Tags: xslt, xpath

love the stuff - newbie Æthelred here

I have a XSLT 1.0 file pulling in a secondary XML (to a variable) to build a table
    `<xsl:variable name="table_values" select="document('./table_variants/external_table.xml')/xml/channel_1"/>`

I then get the values i need from the variable, eg:
    `<xsl:value-of select="$table_values/monkey/tennis/@medals"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$table_values/monkey/tennis/@bananas"/>`

What i want to do is have the first XML trigger/steer where to look for the table data.
I hoped i could, within the triggered XML, state the last part of the xpath - the 'channel_1' or 'channel_2', 
    `<xsl:value-of select="xml/external_table_channel_to_use"/>`
but apparently i cannot create a xpath on the fly like that

Please - What can i do?

Comment: What do you mean by calling an xml? You want a dynamic xpath based on some .xml values?

Comment: yeah - (i believe) that is what i am after. 
Is the secondary file just fluff then (to the question)

Comment: Can't you just take into account all possibilities and use <xsl:choose> or specific <xsl:template select="..."/> to cover all your needs? You can even call specific named templates based on your condiitons.

Comment: sorry i dont think i can - in the example there may be new 'channels' added to the table (and the xml with the value) but the xslt is meant to be static

Comment: Please post your .xml file (a small portion of it) so we can understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What i want to do is have the first XML trigger/steer where to look
>   for the table data. I hoped i could, within the triggered XML, state
>   the last part of the xpath - the 'channel_1' or 'channel_2',
>   `<xsl:value-of select="xml/external_table_channel_to_use"/>` but
>   apparently i cannot create a xpath on the fly like that
>
> Please - What can i do?

This can easily be done just extending the code that you already have.

**Change this**:

```
<xsl:variable name="table_values" select=
"document('./table_variants/external_table.xml')/xml/channel_1"/>
```

**to this**:

```
    <xsl:variable name="table_values" select=
        "document('./table_variants/external_table.xml')
                           /xml/*[name() = $channelName"/>
```

Needless to say, the variable (or global, external param) `$channelName` should have a value that is the (string) name of the element you want to use in the last location step of the XPath expression.

Comment: Brilliant - Thankyou & thankyou for all your other post to other people that have helped me - i was wondering how long before i bumped into Mr. XSLT himself, the great Dimitre ;-)